# How to report daily from two table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, report

How to get daily report if i have two table (income and outcome)?.

```
    structure table
    income  --> id | date_in  | total_in  |
    outcome --> id | date_out | total_out |
```

I want SUM(total_in) and SUM(total_out) per day/daily.
How to get data like this, :

```
    ======================================================
    | Date       | Total In | Total Out | Profit(out-in) |
    --------------------------------------------------
    | 01-01-2017 | 100      | 100       | 0              |
    | 02-01-2017 | 100      | 200       | 100            |
    | 02-01-2017 | 100      | 300       | 200            |
    | ---------- | ---      | ---       | -              |
    | 31-01-2017 | 100      | 400       | 300            |
    ======================================================
```

I try this code but its can show from one table only:

```
SELECT date, COALESCE(SUM(i.total_in), 0) AS `total income`
FROM ( SELECT ADDDATE(('2017-01-01'),ROW-1) AS date
FROM ( SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS ROW
FROM (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6
    UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9) t,(SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
    UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) t2,
    (SELECT @row:=0) r ) n WHERE n.row <= ( SELECT DATEDIFF(MAX(LAST_DAY('2017-01-01')), MIN('2017-01-01')) FROM
    `income`)+ 1) dt LEFT JOIN `income` i ON dt.date = i.`date_income`GROUP BY dt.date;
```

How to get value from two tables, its only from 1 table (income), how it can join with outcome?

Comment: Show your table structures and data and explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok. this is my tables
income(id, date_in, total) &
outcome(id, date_out, total)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

create primary key date_id  in Income table  and then use date_id in second Outcome table